# how to use the STRING parameter in put-image?

Tags: images, overlays, image-mode

I want to temporarily insert an image and a newline in the buffer, all using `put-image`.  That is, I want the buffer to look like this:

```
[IMAGE]
\newline
```

I want the newline to be part of the overlay.

I understand that the third parameter (`STRING`) in `put-image` can be used to achieve that effect.  But I am not sure about how to set that parameter.  The code I have unsuccessfully tried is this:

```
(put-image (create-image "image.gif") (point) #(" \n" 0 1 (display)))
```

For which I get the error "Odd length text property list". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the `STRING` parameter here.  The docs state it's a string used as the `before-string` property with an image on top of it. Therefore, if you do `(put-image (create-image "image.gif") (point) "Some image")`, "Some image" would be displayed before point weren't it for the image layered on top of it which visually replaces that text.  You can check this for yourself by trying out that snippet in a graphical and textual Emacs instance and will notice the textual one will indeed display your string (but obviously not your image), sort of like alt-tags in HTML do.  In fact, I assume this is the intended usecase for that parameter in `put-image`.

In other words, `put-image` is the wrong function for that level of control over overlays.  Here's an example that should achieve what you're asking for:

```
(let ((ov (make-overlay (point) (point))))
  (overlay-put ov 'before-string (propertize " " 'display (create-image "image.gif")))
  (overlay-put ov 'after-string "\n"))
```